# how to update two joined table with queryBuilder in symfony3

Tags: symfony-3.3

How to update fields of two tables which are joined. 
it's showing error.

> message": "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 271 near 'a.artisanName':
>   Error: 'a' is not defined.",

```
    "class": "Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\QueryException",  

 $query = $qb->update("MainBundle:ArtisanUser", 'au')
                ->join("au.Artisan", 'a')
                ->set('au.firstName', $qb->expr()->literal($parameter['params']['firstName']))
                ->set('au.lastName', $qb->expr()->literal($parameter['params']['lastName']))
                ->set('au.email', $qb->expr()->literal($parameter['params']['email']))
                ->set('au.dateOfBirth', $qb->expr()->literal($dob))
                ->set('au.gender', $qb->expr()->literal($parameter['params']['gender']))
                ->set('au.profilePicture', $qb->expr()->literal($parameter['params']['profilePicture']))
                ->set('au.userLang', $qb->expr()->literal($parameter['params']['userLang']))
                ->set('au.updatedAt', $qb->expr()->literal($updatedAt))
                ->set('au.updatedBy', $qb->expr()->literal($parameter['params']['artisanUserId']))
                ->set('a.artisanName',$qb->expr()->literal($parameter['params']['ArtisanName']))
                ->where('au.id = ?1')            
                ->setParameter(1, $parameter['params']['artisanUserId'])            
                ->getQuery();
            $data = $query->execute();
```